# mvc 5 start javascript timer after postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm new to MVC, so I'm assuming I'm going about this wrong, but I can't seem to wrap my head around this. I have a small web app that is used to track time spent working on projects. The web forms version just has and update panel with a couple text boxes and a button, and below that a grid & repeater to display the projects by id & date. One of the text boxes allows me to enter whatever the project number is and the button starts the timer, which is then displayed in the second text box. The button text switches between Start/Stop.

The web form version is using the PRG pattern so if I click refresh , it won't perform another POST. So the button click saves my start time & project to the database and then redirects to the same page where I use RegisterStartupScript to fire the timer. The caveat here is I need to pass the current start time of the running project to the js function, if one is running, otherwise I pass null.

What I'm stuck on is how to get this working the same way in MVC. There is no update panel, and I think the whole view is being refreshed because I can the see the timer start immediately (showing 00:00:01), but then the textbox goes blank. Right now, my two text boxes & button are in an Ajax.BeginForm, the rest of the data is in a partial view. I also understand the AjaxHelper is deprecated, so I'd like to know how to achieve the same with jQuery.

Here's my controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        LoadDic(false);
        VerifyDic();

        return View(db.GetAll().ToList());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection values)
    {
        var project = values["ProjectDescTextBox"];
        ViewData["ProjectText"] = project; 
        ViewData["ServerButtonText"] = "Start";

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(project)) 
            return View(db.GetAll().ToList());

        // this removes the milliseconds...
        var dt = new DateTime((DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond) * TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond);

        //TODO: make sure we're getting today's entry...
        var existing = db.GetAll().FirstOrDefault(t => t.Project == project);

        if (existing != null)
        {
            if (existing.TotalSeconds.HasValue)
            {
                if (existing.StartTime < existing.EndTime)
                    existing.StartTime = dt;
                else
                {
                    existing.EndTime = dt;
                    existing.TotalSeconds = existing.TotalSeconds + Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(dt.Subtract(existing.StartTime.Value).TotalSeconds));
                }
            }
            // if total seconds is null, this is the first time we've stopped; get start time, add time span, update record
            else
            {
                existing.EndTime = dt;
                existing.TotalSeconds = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(dt.Subtract(existing.StartTime.Value).TotalSeconds));
            }

            Edit(existing);
        }
        else
        {
            existing = new TimeEntry { Project = project, StartTime = DateTime.Now };
            Create(existing);
        }

        return View(db.GetAll().ToList());

    }
```

Here's my view:

```
@section Javascript
{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/Timer.js")"></script>
}


@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "TimeTracker", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST"  }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.TextBox("ProjectDescTextBox", @ViewData["ProjectText"], new { @class = "TextBox" })
    <input type="text" id="htmlTimer" class="TextBox" />
    <input id="ServerButton" type="submit" class="Button" value='@ViewData["ServerButtonText"]' onclick='doTimer(@ViewData["CurrentStartTime"]);' />
}

@Html.Partial("GridDataPartialView")
```

The timer itself works fine if it's not inside the form, but then I don't get my project value posted back when I click the start button.

Can anyone see what's wrong with this or what I need to do to keep the timer running on the client? I'm sure there's a way to click a button, do some work on the server (i.e. save to db), and send some data back to the client to start the timer, I just can't seem to get both working; I can either save the data --OR-- start the timer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", "TimeTracker", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess="return function() {doTimer('" + ViewData["CurrentStartTime"] + "');}()"  }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.TextBox("ProjectDescTextBox", @ViewData["ProjectText"], new { @class = "TextBox" })
    <input type="text" id="htmlTimer" class="TextBox" />
    <input id="ServerButton" type="submit" class="Button" value='@ViewData["ServerButtonText"]'  />
}
```

You might need to tweak the onsuccess a bit